# Learning swift ui layout HSTACKS and VSTACKS

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am a learning exercise trying to copy the ui interface to a popular fast food app am only learning swift ui but am trying my best.

This is how it looks

[image]

When I try the below code its not alliging correctly if
import SwiftUI

```
struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
    VStack()
    {
    Image("logo")
    Text("Choose Your Best Meal")
    Text("Mcdolands")
         .padding()
     }

    ScrollView{
    HStack(spacing: 0){
     
        Button(action: {
                print("sign up bin tapped")
            }) {
                Text("Menu")
                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: 50)
                    .font(.system(size: 18))
                    .padding()
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .overlay(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                            .stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 2)
                )
            }
            .background(Color.yellow) // If you have this
            .cornerRadius(5)         // You also need the cornerRadius here
        
        Button(action: {
                print("sign up bin tapped")
            }) {
                Text("Offer")
                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: 50)
                    .font(.system(size: 18))
                    .padding()
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
             
                
            }
            .background(Color.yellow) // If you have this
            .cornerRadius(5)         // You also need the cornerRadius here
        
        
        Button(action: {
                print("sign up bin tapped")
            }) {
                Text("Offer")
                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: 50)
                    .font(.system(size: 18))
                    .padding()
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                     
                
            }
            .background(Color.yellow) // If you have this
            .cornerRadius(5)         // You also need the cornerRadius here
        
        
        Button(action: {
                print("sign up bin tapped")
            }) {
                Text("Offer")
                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: 50)
                    .font(.system(size: 18))
                    .padding()
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                  
            }
            .background(Color.yellow) // If you have this
            .cornerRadius(5)         // You also need the cornerRadius here
        
    }

        VStack( ){
            HStack( ) {
              Image("bigmac")
               Text("Big Mac")
                    Spacer()
                VStack{
                    Text("Meal")
                    Text("£5.00")
                }
                
            }
            HStack{
            Image("chickensandwhich")

          Text("Chicken SandWhich")
            }
      
            HStack{
            Image("doubleqpwithchees")

          Text("Some text here")
            }
                        
                        
         }        .fixedSize()

        Spacer()

    }

}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
 static var previews: some View {
    ContentView()
 }
}
}
```

I suppose this should be a collection view or list view but am not into my learning path enough how to data bound those to a list using model.

So for now what I want is Big Mac title and the meal cost and price to be vertical but still be in a HSTACK,

I do have a strut for my menu items as defined as

```
struct MenuItem {
  let name:String
  let description:String
  let imageUrl :String
  let caroloriesK:Decimal
  let caroloriesJ:Decimal
  let price :Decimal
  let mealprice:Decimal
 
 }
```

Comment: Put a vstack inside the hstack

Comment: How would i put it jn a listview though I thjnk that what i need more

Comment: Try the [Apple SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui)

Answer (score 0):

Make a small adjustment by putting everything except the Image in the VStack inside the HStack. Now your title, meal, price will be in vertical while still inside HStack.

```
VStack {
        HStack {
           Image("bigmac")               
           VStack{
                Text("Big Mac")
                Text("Meal")
                Text("£5.00")
           }
            
        }
       
}
```